# Reusing screens created in compact framework?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework

I've created a screen in compact framework using the form editor, is there a way I can grab this screen or at least some components of it and use them in multiple places in the compact framework app?

Comment: as in Visual Inheritance? or for some components simply encapsulate them as User Controls?

Comment: a controlw ould be preferable..

Comment: the question title seems to allude to something about WinForms to CF, but your question text just talks about CF. Could you elaborate on what you're looking for?

Comment: I meant compact framework, nothing to do with desktop Winforms...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need to look at [UserControls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.usercontrol%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).  They let you create add one or more controls to a surface (the UserControl), and then you can add that UserControl to as many forms in your application as you want.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, tcarvin is right, just create a user control and then reuse this in your compact framework application as often as you need.

To start right click in VS on the project name in solution explorer:

[image: Add user control]

In the popup menu click Add and then UserControl. Accept or change the file name for the user control and then you are looking at the empty user control:

[image: Add User Control design view 01]

You can now resize the user control canvas and then place other controls as buttons, labels, textboxes etc. on it:

[image: A simple user control]

You can then also enter code for button events etc. In the example one can add code to use openfiledialog to select a file and the filename will then displayed in the textbox.
When you are ready, you have to build your solution to get an updated control list on the left in visual studio. Back to a window form design view, you can then place your usercontrol:

[image: Usercontrol place inside winform]

Is that simple?

You can also build a library with user controls and then reuse your controls in every compact framework project where you reference the library.

~josef